# Paypal IPN Verification from return_url is INVALID but from notify_url is VERIFIED

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using Paypal subscription, standard website button. So for this question, the payment_type is subscr_signup, for creating user account for your new user. My HTML button form has values for "notify_url" set to http://domain.com/billing/ipn, "return" set to http://domain.com/billing/thankyou, and "rm" set to 2

With this, when someone completes the payment, s/he will be redirected to our thank you page, along with the IPN data in POST. I got that. But when I verify it with Paypal, I got an INVALID response. Now, here's the strange thing, we should also get the data to our IPN notify_url, right? And we did, but this time, verifying it to Paypal returns VERIFIED.

I notice some differences in the data that is sent.

Data for RETURN thank you page - INVALID (JSON-ified)

```
{
"txn_type": "subscr_signup",
"subscr_id": "I-HHTJ0ANUHKRU",
"last_name": "Ismail",
"residence_country": "CA",
"mc_currency": "USD",
"item_name": "Individual eStudio Plan",
"business": "business@kengkawan.com",
"amount3": "99.00",
"recurring": "1",
"address_street": "1 Maire-Victorin",
"payer_status": "verified",
"payer_email": "customer@kengkawan.com",
"address_status": "confirmed",
"first_name": "Iszuddin",
"receiver_email": "business@kengkawan.com",
"address_country_code": "CA",
"payer_id": "LYRHTKFEH45M8",
"address_city": "Toronto",
"reattempt": "1",
"item_number": "IND",
"address_state": "Ontario",
"subscr_date": "22:52:19 Oct 29, 2014 PDT",
"address_zip": "M5A 1E1",
"charset": "windows-1252",
"period3": "1 Y",
"address_country": "Canada",
"mc_amount3": "99.00",
"address_name": "Iszuddin Ismail",
"auth": "AUjfQ4uRNLr22YfSNPGR1YLm5w81cYyFjf9PEu7mVGSLTp2cFD67opAIXJ-Dtsnw4KEXlF0Y268Ks9VmrwpDRrg",
"form_charset": "UTF-8"
}
```

Data for NOTIFY_URL, backend IPN data - VERIFIED (JSON-ified)

```
{
"txn_type": "subscr_signup",
"subscr_id": "I-HHTJ0ANUHKRU",
"last_name": "Ismail",
"residence_country": "CA",
"mc_currency": "USD",
"item_name": "Individual eStudio Plan",
"business": "business@kengkawan.com",
"amount3": "99.00",
"recurring": "1",
"address_street": "1 Maire-Victorin",
"verify_sign": "Ajiy6YmBz00sV0oT2S-obuaQ3kehAQO0-T8GJFKpiQnaRzRv7.oJ5Eqy",
"payer_status": "verified",
"test_ipn": "1",
"payer_email": "customer@kengkawan.com",
"address_status": "confirmed",
"first_name": "Iszuddin",
"receiver_email": "business@kengkawan.com",
"address_country_code": "CA",
"payer_id": "LYRHTKFEH45M8",
"address_city": "Toronto",
"reattempt": "1",
"item_number": "IND",
"address_state": "Ontario",
"subscr_date": "22:52:19 Oct 29, 2014 PDT",
"address_zip": "M5A 1E1",
"charset": "windows-1252",
"notify_version": "3.8",
"period3": "1 Y",
"address_country": "Canada",
"mc_amount3": "99.00",
"address_name": "Iszuddin Ismail",
"ipn_track_id": "698ae88a36ef9"
}
```

Since I do get expected response (VERIFIED or INVALID), I believe my verification code for Paypal IPN is correct. But just in case, here is my HTML button code.

```
            <form action="<?php echo $this->url?>" method="post" name="ppform">
         <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
         <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $this->paypal_email; ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $selected_plan['name'] ?>"> 
         <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $selected_plan['code'] ?>"> 
         <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="<?php echo $selected_plan['price']; ?>"> <!-- subscription price -->
         <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">  <!-- rebill every x value -->
         <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="<?php echo $selected_plan['recurring_period'] ?>">  <!-- interval M=month/W=week/Y=year -->
         <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"> <!-- Is this recurring 1=yes/0=no -->
         <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $selected_plan['currency'] ?>">
         <!-- <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"> -->
         <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
         <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo site_url('billing/ipn') ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo site_url('billing/thankyou') ?>">

        </form>
```

Comment: I think the question is incomplete/unclear, you said in a comment below you use PDT now, you should update the question with this info. Please note you can and maybe should implement BOTH IPN and PDT, as described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/). Please also specify what programming language you are using (PHP maybe?) and add a tag for that as it will increase your chances of getting a response. Are you using Sandbox for testing?

Comment: Please post some code as well. Example code (PHP, .Net, Coldfusion etc) for implementing IPN [here](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples), example code for implementing PDT [here](https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples)

Answer (score 1):

**return_url** do not recieve any payment/IPN information. Usually it should be just a static page which displays "Thank you, come again".

You should verify IPN messages with **notify_url**. You need to send recieved payment data **exactly** the same way it was recieved. If you recieve INVALID error on a good request, you should double check encoding in which you get the request, store in php and send back. You can use [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) to be sure in the payment code.

Please note IPN sends a bunch of messages on Subscription user registration, payment processing and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In a forum, I was advised to make use of PDT to handle return traffic. So that's what I did. My system still logs IPN data on the backend, receiving subscr_signup and subscr_payment transaction type. But for handling users after payment has been made, I use PDT data now. It requires a bit of settings update in the Paypal account. And then, based on my the GET tx parameter and my secret PDT token, I can request the full data of the transaction. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/

Comment: return_url can receive payment info if using PDT (as it seems to be the case).